# Associate number with leading zeros with one without

Tags: decimal-expansion, natural-numbers

Is there a way to make a unique association between a natural number with leading zeros with a natural number that has no leading zeros?

I have thought about this question for long enough to conclude that it seems impossible, although I am not 100% sure.

N.B. I am talking about decimal naturals.

Comment: What is a natural number with leading zeroes?

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen, I included the tag "decimal-expansion" when I posted the question, now I guess I should have included this information in the question body as well.

Comment: what is unique association you are talking about ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that by *unique association* you mean a bijection. Setting $A = \{0, 1, \ldots, 9\}$, $B = \{1, \ldots, 9\}$ and adopting the notation used for [regular languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language), the set of natural numbers with leading zeroes is $L = 0^+A^*$ and the set of natural numbers without leading zeroes is $N = BA^*$. Since both sets are countable, there is certainly a bijection between them.

One way (probably not the simplest one) would be to order [lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order) the elements of $L$ and $M$. This would give two bijections $f:L \to {\Bbb N}$ and $g:M \to {\Bbb N}$ associating to each element its lexicographic rank and it just remains to consider the bijection $g^{-1}\circ f: L \to M$.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer.